# Mismatch version between pip and python

Tags: python

I have the following versions for python and pip as below.

```
ramirami-pc:lib sclee01$ pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
ramirami-pc:lib sclee01$ python --version
Python 3.8.16
ramirami-pc:lib sclee01$
```

As you can see, python is 3.8.16 but the pip is 3.10 in the anaconda3.

It can be a problems in managing python packages for development?

And if so, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually the safest option is >python -m pip install XXX. That can make sure the installation work on the python. But it may count as a workaround, not the solution...

Comment: This mismatch in versions can lead to conflicts and compatibility issues when installing or managing packages. In your case I would recommend Update pip, Create a virtual environment and after uninstall pip and python again.